# opencv HSV colorspace

Tags: c++, opencv

How do I convert a 16-bit, single-channel image to a 16-bit, three-channel image in the HSV color space?

I aim to maintain a 16-bit depth throughout the process. Firstly, I converted the image to an 8-bit single channel. Then, I applied the COLOR_GRAY2BGR conversion, followed by the COLOR_BGR2HSV transformation. Subsequently, I divided the image based on intensity into distinct regions and assigned corresponding Hue (H), Saturation (S), and Value (V) intensity values to each channel. Finally, I converted it back to 16-bit depth and placed the first intensity as the Value (V) channel

Comment: How do you plan to come up with any actual color information from a grey scale image ?

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your [mcve].

Comment: In your first step, you already seem to break the requirement in maintaining 16-bit depth. | Assuming that Y is the grayscale value, then `GRAY2BGR` sets all 3 of the BGR channels to the same value `Y`. Applying `BGR2HSV` to the result means that: `V=Y`, `S=(Y-Y)/Y=0`, and `H=0` (since `R=G=B=Y`). So most of  of those processing steps don't seem to make much sense, they don't really achieve anything. | You need to explain better what it is you want to achieve, why you need 16 bit depth in the output, what format you want to save it in, etc.

Comment: Does this help `CV_GRAY2BGR565`?